# How to extract e-mail or domain from mixed data file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, grep, sed, awk

File content:

```
17541   From Email      subscription@test.com      Inbound
Policy Manager  Envelope Analysis
Profiler
17541   From Email      subscription@yahoo.com      Inbound
Policy Manager  Envelope Analysis
Profiler
17541   From Domain      test.co.uk      Inbound
Policy Manager  Envelope Analysis
Profiler
17541   From Domain      yahoo.co.uk      Inbound
Policy Manager  Envelope Analysis
Profiler
17541   From Email      subscription@test.com      Inbound
Policy Manager  Envelope Analysis
Profiler
```

I use that command to extract e-mails and convert them to the new format,but I'm not able to extract domains. I use "sort -u" because some mails are duplicate in the file.

```
cat 1| grep -E -o "\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\b"|sed -e 's/^/E,/'|sort -u
```

Expected view after grep domains:

```
test.co.uk
yahoo.co.uk
```

Comment: What kind of output are you expecting?

Comment: I get this on three separate lines when I try  `E,subscription@test.com` `E,subscription@yahoo.com` `E,subscription@test.com` . How does that differ from what you want?

Comment: I edit my requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grep expression is fine, it's the sed one that doesn't work, change it to:

```
< 1 grep -Eo '\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\b' | sed -e 's/[^@]*@//' | sort -u
```

Assuming the input file is called `1`. You could also do the whole thing with grep:

```
< 1 grep -Eo '\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\b' | grep -Eo '[^@]+$' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` one-liner gives the output that you desire

```
awk '/From Email/ { if( !match($4,"@") ){ print $4 } }' inputfile
```

It selects the lines containing 'From Email' and checks whether the fourth column contains a @. You can use `match` with regular expressions to match it to a domain and not a e-mailaddress if you like.

Comment: Thank you Bernard but that not work. There is not output.

Comment: I have mistake in the description of the question now is correct.
When is domain are present like that "17541   From Domain      test.co.uk      Inbound"

Comment: And I get solution for my self thank you you answer give me the right direction where is my error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep command for extraction of email from data file:

```
 grep -oe "[a-zA-Z0-9._]\+@[a-zA-Z]\+.[a-zA-Z]\+" abc.txt
```

this command will give you the all email adresses.

Comment: This is a very poor regex for email. See [Valid & invalid email](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples) and [Regex for email address (RFC 822)](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1128429)